# Custom label for FieldPanel in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

Is there any way to set custom label to FieldPanel in Wagtail? I want to do something like:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('intro', label = "My custom label")
    ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The model field accepts a `verbose_name` property, which will be picked up for use as a form field label:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="My custom label")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('intro')
    ]
```